# git 403 error in windows

Tags: git, apache, http

software visions in my environment

```
    git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0
    apache version httpd-2.2.25
```

I create bare git repositories in Repositories folder

I configure git with apache in my windows 32 bit machine,

I added the following code in httpd.conf file

```
    after restarting apache
    in my browser it  display the all the repositories. it's works in browser.
    but I try to clone the git repo in my command client it prompt the error like


    Cloning into 'testrepo'...
    fatal: unable to access 'http://localhost/testrepo.git/': The requested URL returned
    error: 403


    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/Repositories
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[Apache Git server on Windows^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                    "C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"

    DocumentRoot "C:/Repositories"

    <Directory "C:/Repositories">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the ScriptAliasMatch into one line:

`ScriptAliasMatch "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | info/refs | objects/(info/[^/]+ | [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx)) |  git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" "C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"`

1. Make sure, that You have `git-daemon-export-ok` empty file in Your repo

Those are things that helped me. Another thing, which I'm not sure of is specifying path in `<Directory ...>` if You have applied `DocumentRoot "C:/Repositories"` before.